# Run a typescript file from package.json?

Tags: typescript, package.json

I have a TypeScript project with only have one JavaScript file `testrunner.js` that I would also like to convert to TS.

I currently run the testrunner with yarn using a `package.json` script

```
"test": "node testrunner"
```

When I convert my testrunner file to ts, I change my `package.json` script as follows

```
"test": "tsc testrunner"
```

I get two problems that I am unsure about how to solve:

- It seems like the command line execution of `tsc` is not picking up the `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json. Is it possible to pick these up? I tried using the `project` option, but got a message that "Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line"
- TSC outputs a JS file. Would it be possible have TSC compile and run the testrunner on the fly without outputting a JS file?

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node ts-node to compile & execute the code. but i think it would still output the js file.

Comment: For the first issue, please, share here your tsconfig.json. TSC should read the compilerOptions from there directly. About the second one, you could use, as @AnuragHazra suggests, `ts-node`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run [ts-node in script mode](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#shell).

**ts-node cli options**

`ts-node` supports `--print` (`-p`), `--eval` (`-e`), `--require` (`-r`) and `--interactive` (`-i`) similar to the [node.js CLI options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html).

- `-s, --script-mode` Resolve config relative to the directory of the passed script instead of the current directory. Changes default of `--dir`

For example

```sh
ts-node --script-mode file.js
```

As script for the `package.json`

```js
"test": "ts-node --script-mode testrunner.ts"
```